# beginner project (Web Application)

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, project

i am new and trying my first project.

I am planning to develop a website in which i need a admin to post a list of survey question,
 and the users to answer them and result to be send in mail to the admin

My Question is

1)do i need two website one for admin to post the questions(For Backend Purpose) and one for users(frontend Purpose or is there any other possiblity

2)Can i mix my project with javascript and JSP for interactive Purpose

3)Can i use java for Backend/serverSide(i.e Servlet) or since it is javascript should i use nodeJS

I know Html and css, and
i have recently studied... JSP,Servlet,JDBC

i am currently starting with javascript courses

Answer (score 0):

1) That depends what you mean with website. You can also just make a admin area within your website. So you don't really need two websites. Definition of website can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website

2) You can't really mix JSP an JavaScript. Keep in mind that JSP is on server side and JavaScript is on client side. You could e. g. echo JavaScript code from your JSP. But I'm not sure if that is what you expected.

3) Sure you can use Java on server side.

I think you should do your JavaScript course first. After that you can decide what languages and technologies you want to use and which are the best for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you intend to do that can be handled by just creating a single website. You just need different roles within your single website. An admin role can login with his credentials and add the survey questions. A user can login with his role and can answer the survey.

2 : Yes you would eventually have to mix JavaScript and JSP to make your website interactive.

3: Both NodeJS and Servlets can be used for server side coding purpose. Since you have mentioned that you have recently acquired Servlet knowledge hence going with that would be better.

Comment: Reason please ?

Answer (score -1):

My answer is to do it all in NodeJS because it uses javascript, you can do your entire front end and backend in javascript. Only using one language. You could easily do you admin area with a login section that redirects to a restricted area using express (nodejs module) and still run the front end. All in one file.